# Conditional Merge Fields Open XML SDK

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk, mailmerge

I've looked all over and I can't seem to find any suitable information on Mail Merging (for Conditional Fields) using the Open XML SDK.

We have a conditional merge field, that is consequently made up of further merge fields:

```
,  «C2TITLE» «C2FORE» «C2SUR»
```

Which essentially equates to:

```
IF mergefield C2TITLE «C2TITLE» <> "" ", mergefield C2TITLE «C2TITLE»  mergefield C2FORE «C2FORE» mergefield C2SUR «C2SUR»" ""
```

Half of the problem here we can't understand why the merge field name is repeated twice:

```
mergefield C2TITLE «C2TITLE»
```

But also in the breakdown of the XML (via a Vs2012 watch), we can see the merge fine, but also the 3 fields are repeated, does anyone have an explanation for this?

[image: VS2012 View]

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be most appreciated!

--Edit - Added XML--

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="009621F8" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> IF </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> mergefield C2TITLE </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:instrText>«C2TITLE»</w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">&lt;&gt; "" ",  </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> mergefield C2TITLE </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:instrText>«C2TITLE»</w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> mergefield C</w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">2FORE </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:instrText>«C2FORE»</w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> mergefield C2SUR </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:instrText>«C2SUR»</w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">" "" </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">,  </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> mergefield C2TITLE </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>«C2TITLE»</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> mergefield C2FORE </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>«C2FORE»</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> mergefield C2SUR </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>«C2SUR»</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Comment: It's difficult to be sure without seeing the raw XML, but a possible reason for the "repeat" is that "mergefield C2TITLE" is the merge code (i.e. what would appear as { MERGEFIELD C2TITLE } when viewing field codes in Word, and that «C2TITLE» is the default mergefield result (i.e. the one you see when you view field results, but not in preview mode. But are you inserting «C2TITLE», or seeing it in an existing document.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a bit of sense, if it helps - I've added the XML, well, the offending section

Comment: OK, I have created a simple .docx with MERGEFIELDs to look at the XML Word generates, and (a) for a { MERGEFiELD } outside an IF, Word generates XML similar to yours /except/ it uses <w:t>«C2TITLE»</w:t> instead of <w:instrText>«C2TITLE»</w:instrText>.

Inside the IF, it's more like: <w:fldSimple w:instr=" MERGEFIELD k " ><w:rPr><w:noProof /></w:rPr><w:instrText>1</w:instrText></w:r></w:fldSimple>

Perhaps Word expects <w:t> in some cases but <w:instrtext> in others, e.g. outside v. inside a nested field, or inside a field defined via fldSimple rather than a comples field code.

Comment: @bibadiak: Thanks for the info but do you know why we (I work with Stuart who posted the original question) are seeing the same mergefield in both ways. I would have expected to see one or the other, not both.

Comment: Looking at the ISO specification, it looks as if <w:instrtext> should be treated as <w:t> anyway in these circumstances. The spec. can sometimes be a little vague. Or it could be Word just getting it wrong .